# CSS: How to make single div of multiple divs within a div show on the bottom

Tags: css, styles, css-position

If I have a div that appears like a big square, and child divs that show values within that div, how do I get one of those divs to show on the bottom regardless of the space the others consume at the top. Hope that makes sense....

Here is a fiddle for example...I want child 3 to not be one of the tile like elements in the parent div, just a note along the bottom kind of thing. [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rbxE8/8/)

html:

```
<div id='parent'>

    <div id='child1' class='each-element'>Child 1</div>
    <div id='child2' class='each-element'>Child 2</div>
    <div id='child3' class='each-element'>Child 3</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#parent{
    min-height:300px;
    max-height:310px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    width:400px;
    padding:1%;
}

div.each-element{
    border:2px solid #2d2d2d;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'segoe ui';
    margin:2%;
    padding:1%;
}

#child3{
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    margin:0

}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rbxE8/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you set the position on the parent div to relative, and then the position on the child 3 div to absolute. Then also on the child 3 div set the bottom to zero and width to 100% like:

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rbxE8/10/)**

```
#parent {
    min-height:300px;
    max-height:310px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    width:400px;
    padding:1%;
    position:relative;
}
div.each-element {
    border:2px solid #2d2d2d;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'segoe ui';
    margin:2%;
    padding:1%;
}
#child3 {
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    margin:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting the child 3 div to be fixed to the bottom of the parent div?

```
#parent{
   position: relative;
}

#child3{
   bottom: 0;
   position: absolute;
}
```